# xls Drools Valid Values

Tags: drools, xls

[My xls column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAP5P.png)

I have the column "Channel Name", which contains valid values for channel name attribute. For each of those valid channel name I need to set blueReport.setStatus(true). How can I set blueReport.setStatus(false) if a channel name is not on that list of valid channel names?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to set only two values in your Action i.e either "true" or "false". If so, you should use blueReport.setStatus($param); in the Action-Rule. Set the corresponding value "true"or "false" against that rule below the Action column of blueReport.setStatus($param)

Comment: Under the Channel Name (there are only valid channel name), other than those 3 valid values, other channel names should have a status of 'false', and there could be hundreds of invalid channel names..